# How to change the name of the index to other values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to change the names of the index of my dataframe but I don`t know why Dataframe.set_index() is not working

```
d1 = {'Numero puntos de venta': [ 350595]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1 )

d2 = {'Numero puntos de venta': [335324]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d2)

bar_heights = pd.concat([bbdd_msm_tamaño,censo_digital_tamaño])
bar_heights.plot.bar()
```

## Now I want to change the name of the index

```
bar_heights.set_index(['MSM', 'Censo'])
```

I expected to get

```
Out[42]:


MSM
350595
Censo
335324
```

But I get the following error: `KeyError: 'MSM'`

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: can you share the exception that occurred?

Comment: is `MSM` already index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` sets an existing column with a name to be the new index. This is not what you want to do, therefore you get an error. Instead, try assigning a simple list to the index like this:

`bar_heights.index = ['MSM', 'Censo']`

Comment: This is working! Thanks, another equivalent solution seems to be bar_heights = bar_heights.set_index([pd.Index(['MSM', 'Censo'])])